# AsyncStorage value is not defined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an singleton Class that uses AsyncStorage.
Follow the code:

```
import ReactNative, { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export default class StorageHandler {
  static async getItem(key) {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  static async setItem(key, value) {
    console.log("Values on StorageHandler", key, value);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the setItem function in a function in a component, follow the function:

```
async onIds(device) {
    console.log("Device info: ", device);
    try {
      await StorageHandler.setItem(StorageConstants.ONESIGNAL_ID, device.userId)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

But i'm getting an error :

```
ReferenceError: value is not defined;
```

The log on StorageHandler returns :

```
Values on StorageHandler onesignal_id xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
```

So, what i'm doing wrong ?
And most important, why is it happening?
I'm starting at react-native so i'm a bit lost.

Edit1 : 
Removed Resolve from getItem catch.

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure that value is a string?
What I would do is enable the debugger and put a breakpoint on the setItem function and step into it to see where it throws that error

Comment: How familiar are you with async, await, and Promises? The way your code is written feels like a code smell and makes me wonder if there's something else going on. Especially since copy pasting the shell of your code and throwing in random strings for key/value gives me no such error. [See example Snack.](https://snack.expo.io/@kameyin/stackoverflow-q-49544067-148212)

Comment: Let's say, that I know angular promises, but this problem just got me crazy.
I just trying everything just for the hope to make it work.
I've tried to use Promises, that's why there is a resolve on catch error in an Async method. Removing it. 
I did see this example.
So I imported the React above the AsyncStorage Import, and it worked.
Then I removed the React and React-Native Imports, and the method  setItem still runs without erros.
Maybe it was an linking error... ? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: I've tried it in another component and it won't work.
So I deleted my application from my device and re-compile, after that it worked.
Maybe it's something to do with the Livereload.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the react-native app from my device and recompile without livereload and it worked.
Maybe it's something wrong with livereload.

Edit: The chrome debugger by default have the option "Pause on Exceptions" on.
Sometimes the promises didn't return an error, and by the act of livereload it seems the chrome is pausing the promises doe to the previous error.
Just turn "Pause on Exceptions" off and it work like a charm.